# Assertion failed: (0), function uv_close, file ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c, line 174 warning

Tags: reactjs

I'm running a `npm run start`, and I get an Assertion warning. What is the problem?

Comment: Check https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10037